# Inserir texto no cabeçalho de uma folha de cálculo a partir do texto contido numa célula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Para configurar o cabeçalho de uma folha de cálculo vou a Configurar Página > Cabeçalho/Rodapé > Personalizar cabeçalho.
Vamos supor que, na secção central, quero que apareça um título que está na célula A1.
Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 1):

Tudo indica que o que eu quero não é possível sem recorrer ao VBA ([link](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,34178,00.asp));
Aparentemente teria que fazer uma macro para preencher a secção do cabeçalho respetiva.

```
Sub HeaderFromA1()
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola!
Infelizmente com o recurso Cabeçalho/rodapé da Configuração de Página do Excel não é possível, mas você consegue o mesmo resultado com outro recurso sem a utilização de VBA.

1. No Excel, clique na guia LAYOUT DA PÁGINA
2. Em seguida clique em IMPRIMIR TÍTULOS
3. Na janela que irá abrir, clique na guia PLANILHA
4. No campo "Linhas a repetir na parte superior", escolha a célula ou linha inteira que deseja utilizar como cabeçalho ou rodapé para todas as páginas.
5. Clique em OK e visualize a impressão

Abraços!!
www.learnoffice.com.br